# Skrollr.js relative key frames and best practices

Tags: animation, parallax, skrollr

I'm not sure if something I want to do is possible with skrollr, it doesn't seem to be possible but maybe I am misunderstanding.  I would like to be able to describe keyframes in scroll points relative to other keyframe events, as in "start this animation event 500px after another element's animation event", and wondering what the best practice is.  I am working on a large page of multiple sections of animated content.  Each section scrolls to the top, then becomes temporarily fixed as multiple animations occur within the section on many key frames, then once that section's animations are done it scrolls up off the screen and the next section comes into view and does it's own animating, and so on (not unlike the main [skrollr demo](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/) but more complex with many more animation events).  My main issue is that I want to be able to easily edit in the future each sections' animation timings independently, for example to adjust little details here and there as needed, anticipating some back-and-forth with the artists and clients I'm working with.  But when relying on an absolute `scrollTop` for all timings, this becomes problematic because one little timing change means I have to adjust all subsequent timings throughout the remainder of the page.  To get around this I am using constants to denote the start of each animated section so that at least I can have each animated section be timed relative to its start, as in:

```
<style type="text/css">
#fixedanimatedcontent1, #fixedanimatedcontent2 {position: fixed;}
</style> 

<section id="fixedanimatedcontent1" data-_fixedanimstart1--630="top:100%;" data-_fixedanimstart1="top:0%;" data-_fixedanimstart1-1500="top:0%;" data-_fixedanimstart2="top:-100%;">        
        <div data-_fixedanimstart1="width: 0%;" data-_fixedanimstart1-470="width: 100%"></div>
        <img src="x.png" data-_fixedanimstart1-270="opacity: 0;" data-_fixedanimstart1-670="opacity: 1;" data-_fixedanimstart1-1170="opacity: 0;" />
</section>

<section id="fixedanimatedcontent2" data-_fixedanimstart2--630="top:100%;" data-_fixedanimstart2="top:0%;" data-_fixedanimstart2-2000="top:0%;" data-_fixedanimstart3="top:-100%;">
        <img src="y.png" data-_fixedanimstart2-500="opacity: 0;" data-_fixedanimstart2-1000="opacity: 1;" data-_fixedanimstart2-1500="opacity: 0;" />
</section>
```

But even still, for complex sequences making a small timing change will be a bit of a mess, requiring at the least changing all key frame offsets within that section, and probably also changing constant values.  Looking at my example above, 2 questions:

1) Is there a way to describe a relative keyframe that, let's say, begins 500px after section `#fixedanimatedcontent2`'s top=0%?  I know I can do `data-top`, but in my setup `#fixedanimatedcontent2` becomes fixed at the top for some time once it hits the top.  So how do I describe a keyframe that I want to begin 500px of scrolling after `#fixedanimatedcontent2` hits `data-top`? Is this not possible within the syntax of "relative key frames" since offsets are only relative to element position in the viewport?  If this were doable somehow, I wouldn't have to rely on constants so much...

2) How about a keyframe that begins when section `#fixedanimatedcontent2`'s `<img>` reaches an opacity of 1? That way I could later if I needed make a change in the length of that `<img>`'s opacity interpolation without having to change all subsequent key frame timings.  Pretty sure this is not possible but had to ask...

So: Am I misunderstanding what is the best way to do this sort of relative sequencing most efficiently?  Or is using constants as in the example above the best practice?

(this was a really verbose post, sorry!)

Answer (score 0):

It is very well possible in skrollrjs. I am telling nothing different from skrollrjs documentation. If you look carefully there, there are two modes for keyframes

1. absolute
2. relative

I think you wanted to use relative mode. So, i would answer each of your questions orderly.

1) Is there a way to describe a relative keyframe that, let's say, begins 500px after section #fixedanimatedcontent2's top=0%? I know I can do data-top, but in my setup #fixedanimatedcontent2 becomes fixed at the top for some time once it hits the top. So how do I describe a keyframe that I want to begin 500px of scrolling after #fixedanimatedcontent2 hits data-top? Is this not possible within the syntax of "relative key frames" since offsets are only relative to element position in the viewport? If this were doable somehow, I wouldn't have to rely on constants so much...

Answer:- It is possible to do that. In relative mode of work, you can define your relative targets and you can define css accordingly. So for your element #fixedanimatedcontent2 when reaches top i would use like following html

You can use following cheatseet for this. This is helpful.
https://ihatetomatoes.net/skrollr-cheatsheet/

I think all you need is already described if you read carefully
https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr